# Swift image picker not working

Tags: ios, swift, image, uiimagepickercontroller, photo

I have look this code several times, even for hour now, but I can find error. :(

There is no error compiling project, no error showing at all, but I just can not pick image, when I press UIImage, nothing happened.

Have similar code in "signUp View Controller" when signing up everything goes well, you can choose (pick) image, and image is properly saved on Firebase.

Also, in this "ProfileTableViewController", everything is show very well, saved image on Firebase is loaded and shown inside Profile View, but can not pick it (press on it) to choose it and change.

Everything else is tested, changed and saved (username or even e-mail), only image gives me problem. Can you please look the code and tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks.

```
import UIKit

class ProfileTableViewController: UITableViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var profileImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var username: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var email: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.title = "Edit Profile"
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ProfileTableViewController.selectPhoto(_:)))
    tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    profileImage.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    profileImage.layer.cornerRadius = profileImage.frame.size.height / 2
    profileImage.clipsToBounds = true

    if let user = DataService.dataService.currentUser {
        username.text = user.displayName
        email.text = user.email
        if user.photoURL != nil {
            if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: user.photoURL!) {
                self.profileImage!.image = UIImage.init(data: data)
        }
    }
} else {
        // No user is signed in

    }
}
func selectPhoto(tap: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePicker.delegate = self
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.Camera) {
        imagePicker.sourceType = .Camera
    } else {
        imagePicker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary
    }
    self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

// UIImagePicker Delegate

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage, editingInfo: [String : AnyObject]?) {
    profileImage.image = image
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: its work  in self.view but not work in the imageView

Comment: set user interaction enable to your `profileImage` and try again

Comment: Thanks @MikeAlter :) I knew it that is something simple I am missing out. Thanks a million! ;)

Comment: you most welcome and happy coding !!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable user interaction on the UIImageView, try this after adding gesture recognizer:

```
profileImage.userInteractionEnabled = true
```

Comment: And how will this make a difference?

Comment: @penatheboss Have you tried it? UIImageView's userInteractionEnabled property is false by default, and it wouldn't respond to any gestures unless you change it to true.

Comment: Can whoever that downvoted this justify the reason for the downvote? To me this sounds like a legitimate possibility. Sometimes we tend to forget these simple stuff

Comment: My apologies; I had read the question incorrectly. This is a valid answer.

Answer (score 0):

I did it Other way by **Checking** `User Interaction Enabled` under "`Interaction`" option, see below image for reference

[image]

Hope it help anybody